# Inductive proof $f(n) = n$ with function composition.

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I need help with a inductive proof. Currently got no idea how to start with this assignment.

Assignment:

Let $f : \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$ be a function, so that the inequality:

$$f \circ f(n) < f(n+1)$$ exists. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

Show that $f(n) = n$. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

I am currently struggling to understand where to start with this one. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please, check if your question is correctly written. I think there is, at least, one typo.

Comment: It's an inequality, not an equation.

Comment: I had to translate the question from another language, where do you think the typo might be for cross reference ?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know if it's a language I understand, but can you put also the question in its original language?

Comment: Es sei f : N0 → N0 eine Abbildung, sodass für alle  n ∈ N0 die Ungleichung
f ◦ f(n) < f(n + 1) (∗)
gilt. Zeigen Sie: ∀n ∈ N0 : f(n) = n. (Language is German)

Comment: Luckily is a language I speak, and I agree with your translation in english.
Here it doesn't say to prove it by induction. Was this your choice to try by induction, or was it suggested somewhere else in the book (or notes)?

Comment: I think "gilt" should be translated as "holds" in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that it is enough to show that any such $f$ is strictly increasing, for then $f(f(n))<f(n+1)$ implies $f(n)<n+1$ and an easy induction shows that $f$ is the identity.

Since the image of $f$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, it has a a smallest element, $m_0$.  Suppose that $f(n)=m_0$ for some $n>0$.  Then $n-1\in \mathbb{N}_0$, and we have $f(f(n-1))<f(n)=m_0$ which contradicts the definition of $m_0$.  However, $f(n)=m_0$ for some natural number $n$, so $f$ attains its minimum at, and only at, $n=0$.

For $k=1,2,\dots$, let $\mathbb{N}_k=\{n\in \mathbb{N}_0\mid n\geq k\}$, and let $f_k$ be the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{N}_k$.   I claim that the minimum value of $f_k$ is attained at, and only at $n=k$.  We have already proved the basis.  Suppose that $k>0$ and that the claim is true for $n=0,1,\dots,k-1$.  $f_k$ attains its minimum $m_k$ at some natural number $n\geq k$.  Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $n>k$.  Then $n-1\geq k$ and we have $f(f(n-1))<f(n)=m_k$.  To show that this is a contradiction, we have only to show that $f(n-1)\geq k$.  The induction hypothesis implies that $f(0), f(1), \dots, f(k-1)$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers, so that $f(k-1)\geq k-1$.  By the induction hypothesis, $f_k$ attains its minimum only at $k-1$, so that $n-1\geq k$ implies $f(n-1)>f(k-1)\geq k-1$, which completes the proof.

I'd like to say a few words about your statement that you couldn't figure out where to start.  That gave me trouble, too.  I tried to start by proving $f(0)=0$, but all I could prove was that $f(n)\neq0$ for $n>0$.  For a short while, I tried to construct a counterexample, but I quickly became convinced that the statement is true.  So then I looked for a weaker condition that would imply the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Being an inductive proof, we start with the smallest number we can find.
In $\mathbb{N}_0$, the smallest number is $0$.
Hence the  first thing we want to show is that $f(0)=0$

You can start by thinking what would happen if $f(0) \neq 0$, considering that $f \circ f (n) < f(n+1) $ for all $n$.

(I will edit if I reach to go further, but the start of the proof should be in this direction)

Comment: This is not an answer.  It's a comment at best.

Comment: I know. I could have actually posted it as a comment, but since he asked where to start, I figured this was kind of an answer, to the question "where do I start from?". 
I don't consider it to be an answer for the proof